# Why can't I extend Clojure's IFn using extend-type?

Tags: java, clojure, clojurescript

I saw David Nolen's talk on ClojureScript where he makes extends IFn to Regexp and so that we can call a regex literal as a fuinction on a string to check for matches.

I tried something similar with Strings in regular Clojure, but I get this exception.
I see that IFn is an interface written in Java but how does the implementation work in CLojrue front.

```
(extend-type java.lang.String
  #_=>    clojure.lang.IFn
  #_=>   (-invoke
  #_=>    ([this index]
  #_=>     (get (seq this) index))))
IllegalArgumentException interface clojure.lang.IFn is not a protocol  clojure.core/extend (core_deftype.clj:742)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exception should give you a hint. `IFn` is not a protocol in Clojure. It is in ClojureScript. You can `extend` protocols, implement Java interfaces, and subclass classes. In this particular case, you cannot even subclass java.lang.String because it's declared final.

Comment: In this case my best bet would be a new type that just wraps a java.lang.String and passes all the calls to it except -invoke and implements IFn ?

Comment: But in `clojure`, keywords can behave like functions e.g. `(:a {:a 36})`. How does it work?

Comment: Keywords are implemented in Java, so they can inherit from the IFn interface, https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Keyword.java

Comment: It seems, then, that there's two issues? 1) IFn is not a protocol. 2) You cannot extend Java classes.